# finding the limit of matrix exponentiation when exponent goes to infinity

Tags: matrices, limits, exponentiation

I have a problem(1) where the solution is more and more precise as I raise a matrix to a higher power. Both matrices and vector are over the real numbers, between 0.0 and 1.0.

I'm looking for $s$ in

$s = V \times M^x$ as $x \to \infty $

This converges, but I'd like to find the limit to which $s$ goes. $M$ sums to 1 on every row, if that helps. I denote vector-matrix multiplication by $\times$. Sorry if this is the wrong symbol. With V and M fixed, are there techniques I can use to compute this limit?

(1) V is a vector of probabilities of being in a given state, M is a transition matrix, giving the probability of going to each state from each state. The problem is to find the chance of being in specific states after infinite iterations.

Comment: "*probability of going from one state to another*"  You are talking about Markov Chains.  Your notation suggests that you are using row vectors rather than column vectors for this... In any event, it is well known that a *Regular* Markov chain will reach a "*steady state*" regardless what the initial state was and will satisfy $sM=s$.  You can solve for $s$ by solving $s(M-I)=0$, i.e. solving for the left-nullspace of $M-I$.

Comment: As for what $M^x$ becomes for the limit... for a regular markov chain, it will consist of repeated copies of $s$ as the rows(?).  (*I am far more used to treating markov chains with column vectors rather than row vectors...*).  On the other hand if it is not a regular markov chain but an absorbing one... there are techniques for that as well.  I'm tired and not willing to rework what I learned to fit for a row-vector narrative... but for a column vector setting an absorbing matrix of the form $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}I&S\\\hline 0&R\end{array}\right]$ you would have...

Comment: ...the limiting matrix become $\left[\begin{array}{c|c}I&S(I-R)^{-1}\\\hline 0&0\end{array}\right]$.  In your case using row vectors... I believe that is just the transpose of this, but I'd try to double-check the order of the multiplication of $S(I-R)^{-1}$

Comment: That is much helpful!